# Existe alguma maneira de recuperar o histórico de todas as queries executadas num servidor MySql?

Tags: mysql, apache

Tenho uma transação em uma tabela de um banco de dados MySql e (php+apache).
Eu queria saber se eu poderia recuperar (seja no log do apache ou no log do MySql) o ip de onde foi gerada a query que fez essa inserção.
Alguma idéia?

Comment: Tem como configurar o log de queries, mas não é possível recuperar o IP, pois todas as queries são executados do mesmo servidor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql

Comment: Na verdade se o servidor de aplicação não está no mesmo _host_ do de banco de dados é possível recuperar este endereço. Mas se o que você deseja é a informação do lado do cliente então a coisa fica mais difícil. Você pode tentar cruzar os _logs_ do Apache e do MySQL mas a solução mais simples é fazer o programa em PHP registrar no _log_ do Apache ou num arquivo próprio a informação que você precisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chama-se *general query log* e vem desabilitado por padrão. Habilitando-o o servidor passará a armazenar cada operação realizada; vale a pena ler a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) sobre o assunto pois é possível criar uma lista de comandos SQL que você não precisa salvar no log.

Comment: era isso mesmo que eu procurava. mas infelizmente o meu nao esta habilitado. vou habilitar para as logs futuras. valeu